# Paypal PHP SDK Functionality of .coveralls.yml

Tags: php, paypal, sdk, payment-gateway

I have downloaded https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/.coveralls.yml

```
# .coveralls.yml configuration

# for php-coveralls
src_dir: lib
coverage_clover: build/coverage/clover.xml
json_path: build/coverage/coveralls-upload.json
```

What is actual functionality of `.coveralls.yml` file? What is meaning of PHP Code Coverage or Coveralls?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is on the Coveralls home page:

> We help you deliver code confidently by showing which parts of your code aren’t covered by your test suite.

The `.coveralls.yml` is the configuration file used when determining the percentage of code covered by the tests of the PayPal-PHP-SDK package. Sometimes you have to exclude some code, you have to define where the output goes and in which format, you do that in such a configuration file and keep it with your code.

Comment: thanks for answer. Means i can use it for any PHP Application newly or custom?

Comment: You could, you just have to adapt it to your application. If you have less than 100% coverage you know that at least part of your code is not tested (unfortunately the reverse doesn't hold).